# a college entrance examination problem! how to find a geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

A Chinese college entrance examination math problem:

> Given an arithmetic progression sequence $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}$, that are all positive real numbers, the common difference of the arithmetic progression is set as $d\;(d\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$. Prove that:
>
> 1. $2^{a_{1}},2^{a_{2}},2^{a_{3}},2^{a_{4}}$ is a geometric progression sequence.
> 2. Whether there exists $a_{1}$ and $d$ such that $a_{1},{a_{2}}^2,{a_{3}}^3  $and $a_{4}^4$ can be formed as a geometric progression? Explain why.
> 3. Whether there exists $a_{1}$ ,$d$, and $n$,$k\;$($n$,$k$ are positive integers) such that $a_{1}^n,a_{2}^{n+k},a_{3}^{n+3k},a_{4}^{n+5k}$ can be formed as a geometric progression? Explain why.

I think the first part is easy, and I am feeling struggled with the part (2) and part (3). This problem is from this year's China's college entrance examination of math. Can someone help me solve it?

Comment: Try $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = 1$.

Comment: sorry,I missed it,d does not equal to 0

Comment: what does "show whether there exists $a_1$" mean in part b once we've been given the sequence $a_i$?

Comment: it means that we need to find that exact number $a_{1}$ and k

Comment: Or, we need to prove we cannot find $a_{1} $ and k, I think we need to use some functions to prove maybe it is impossible to find $a_{1}$ and k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2. Let the numbers be $b-d,b,b+d,b+2d$.  Then $b-d,b^2,(b+d)^3,(b+2d)^4$ are to form  a geometric series.
   We need $(b-d)(b+d)^3=(b^2)^2$.  Let $e=b/d$, then it simplifies to $2e^3-2e-1=0$.
   We need $(b^2)(b+2d)^4=(b+d)^6$.  This simplifies to $2e^5+9e^4+12e^3+e^2-6e-1=0$.
   Do long division to check that the cubic and the quintic do not share a root.
3. I didn't do; perhaps the two polynomials do share a root?

Comment: oh, thanks for this hint!

Comment: looks like you are in the correct direction. finally, I feel this problem is not very fun,just huge computation

Answer (score 2):

$a_k=dk+a_0$ by definition of arithmetic progression, with $a_0:=a_1-d$.

1) A geometric progression $b_k$ by definition satisfies $b_{k+1}/b_k=c$ for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$. Thus if $b_{k}=2^{a_k}$, you can verify this fact directly.

2) Define $b_k=a_k^k$. Then suppose $b_{k+1}/b_k=a_{k+1}^{k+1}/a^k_k=c$. Rearranging, we get:

$$c(dk+a_0)^k=(d(k+1)+a_0)^{k+1}=(dk+a_0+d)^{k+1}=(dk+a_0)^{k+1}(1+d/(dk+a_0))^{k+1}.$$

This gives:

$$c=(dk+a_0)((1+d/(dk+a_0))^{k+1}\geq (dk+a_0),$$

but $c$ must be the same for all $k$, so if $d>0$, this is impossible. Hence $d\leq 0$. But if $d<0$, then $a_k$ will be negative at some point. So $d=0$ gives $c=1$.

3) Can you take it from here?

Comment: how can you get $(dk+a_{0})(1+d/(dk+a_{0}))^{k+1}>=(dk+a_{0})$

Comment: @tiandiao123, It's true under the assumption that $d>0$.

Comment: yeah, at the beginning, you are right . later on , I think there is a little mistake:  in this problem, we only have four terms: $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3} , a_{4} $ instead of infinity

Comment: @tiandiao123: You wrote $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,\ldots$, and $\ldots$ signify infinitely many terms.

Comment: If you really do only have 4 terms, show that the expression that $c$ is equal to cannot be the same constant for $k=1,2,3,4$. You can do this by forming a system of equations for $k=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: Ok , I will try ! thanks